# List all Guest user's Order History in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, json, guest-checkout, order-history

Create a Magento 2 extension to implement guest order history feature.

Please implement with a new controller that takes **parameter(s)**
to query a single order and returns a json with information about order `status, total, items (sku, item_id, price) and total invoiced.`

Use Itdesire as namespace and **OrderController** as module name. **(Itdesire_OrderController)**

Answer (score 1):

> app/code/Itdesire/OrderController/registration.php

```
 <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Itdesire_OrderController',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Itdesire/OrderController/etc/module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Itdesire_OrderController" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/Itdesire/OrderController/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/guestorder/getGuestOrderHistory/:param" method="GET">
        <service class="Itdesire\OrderController\Api\GuestorderInterface" method="getGuestOrderHistory"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

> app/code/Itdesire/OrderController/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Itdesire\OrderController\Api\GuestorderInterface" type="Itdesire\OrderController\Model\Guestorder" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Itdesire/OrderController/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="ordercontroller" id="ordercontroller">
            <module name="Itdesire_OrderController"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/Itdesire/OrderController/Model/Guestorder.php

```
<?php

namespace Itdesire\OrderController\Model;

use Itdesire\OrderController\Api\GuestorderInterface;

/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the calculator service contract.
 */
class Guestorder implements GuestorderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *     
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Return mixed.
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $param.
     * @return mixed.
     */
    public function getGuestOrderHistory($param) {
        $arrayData = $this->getJsonArrayOfGuestOrders($param);
        return $arrayData;
    }

    /**
     * get guest order collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    public function getGuestOrderCollection($param)
    {
        $orderCollecion = $this->orderCollectionFactory
                                ->create()
                                ->addFieldToSelect('*');

        $orderCollecion->addFieldToFilter(
                            'customer_id',
                            array(
                                'null' => true
                            )
                        );

        if ('all' !== $param){
            $orderCollecion->getSelect()->limit((int)$param);
        }

        return $orderCollecion;
    }

    /**
     * format guest order collection into array for json object
     */
    public function getJsonArrayOfGuestOrders($param)
    {
        $jsonArray = [];
        $guestOrderCollection = $this->getGuestOrderCollection($param);
        foreach($guestOrderCollection as $_collection){
            $guestOrderHistory['status'] = $_collection->getStatus();
            $guestOrderHistory['total'] = $_collection->getGrandTotal();
            $allVisibleItems = $_collection->getAllVisibleItems();
            $itemArray = [];
            $qtyInvoiced = 0;
            foreach($allVisibleItems as $_item){
                $qtyInvoiced = $qtyInvoiced + $_item->getQtyInvoiced();
                $_itemArray['sku'] = $_item->getSku();
                $_itemArray['item_id'] = $_item->getItemId();
                $_itemArray['price'] = $_item->getRowTotal();
                $_itemArray['qty_invoiced'] = $_item->getQtyInvoiced();
                $_itemArray['qty'] = $_item->getQtyOrdered();
                $itemArray[] = $_itemArray;
            }
            $guestOrderHistory['qty_invoiced'] = $qtyInvoiced;
            $guestOrderHistory['item'] = $itemArray;
            $jsonArray[] = $guestOrderHistory;
        }
        return $jsonArray;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Itdesire/OrderController/Controller/Guestorderhistory/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Itdesire\OrderController\Controller\Guestorderhistory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $jsonData = $this->getJsonArrayOfGuestOrders();
        return $result->setData($jsonData);
    }

    /**
     * get guest order collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    public function getGuestOrderCollection()
    {
        $orderCollecion = $this->orderCollectionFactory
                                ->create()
                                ->addFieldToSelect('*');

        $orderCollecion->addFieldToFilter(
                            'customer_id',
                            array(
                                'null' => true
                            )
                        );

        $totalGuestOrder = $this->getRequest()->getParam('total_guest_order');
        if ('all' !== $totalGuestOrder){
            $orderCollecion->getSelect()->limit((int)$totalGuestOrder);
        }

        return $orderCollecion;
    }

    /**
     * format guest order collection into array for json object
     */
    public function getJsonArrayOfGuestOrders()
    {
        $jsonArray = [];
        $guestOrderCollection = $this->getGuestOrderCollection();
        foreach($guestOrderCollection as $_collection){
            $guestOrderHistory['increment_id'] = $_collection->getIncrementId();
            $guestOrderHistory['status'] = $_collection->getStatus();
            $guestOrderHistory['total'] = $_collection->getGrandTotal();
            $allVisibleItems = $_collection->getAllVisibleItems();
            $itemArray = [];
            $qtyInvoiced = 0;
            foreach($allVisibleItems as $_item){
                $qtyInvoiced = $qtyInvoiced + $_item->getQtyInvoiced();
                $_itemArray['sku'] = $_item->getSku();
                $_itemArray['item_id'] = $_item->getItemId();
                $_itemArray['price'] = $_item->getRowTotal();
                $_itemArray['qty_invoiced'] = $_item->getQtyInvoiced();
                $_itemArray['qty'] = $_item->getQtyOrdered();
                $itemArray[] = $_itemArray;
            }
            $guestOrderHistory['qty_invoiced'] = $qtyInvoiced;
            $guestOrderHistory['item'] = $itemArray;
            $jsonArray[] = $guestOrderHistory;
        }
        return $jsonArray;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Itdesire/OrderController/Api/GuestorderInterface.php

```
   <?php

namespace Itdesire\OrderController\Api;

/**
 * Defines the service contract for some simple maths functions. The purpose is
 * to demonstrate the definition of a simple web service, not that these
 * functions are really useful in practice. The function prototypes were therefore
 * selected to demonstrate different parameter and return values, not as a good
 * calculator design.
 */
interface GuestorderInterface
{
    /**
     * Return mixed.
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $param.
     * @return mixed.
     */
    public function getGuestOrderHistory($param);
}
```

> How to Run?

```
### Install extension
---------------------------

1. Go to Magento 2 root folder

2. paste all code in a foler app/code/Itdesire/OrderController

3. Enter following commands to enable module:

   php bin/magento module:enable Itdesire_OrderController
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento cache:clean


### How to use
---------------------

Method 1: 
---------
params: total_guest_order --> it can be 1,2,3... ( Numbers of orders to return )
Replace http://localhost/demo/Magento-CE-2.1.4 with your URL and Just hit the url

http://localhost/demo/Magento-CE-2.1.4/index.php/ordercontroller/guestorderhistory?total_guest_order=1


Method 2:
---------
Cut and paste run.php file to your magento root and replace "localhost/demo/Magento-CE-2.1.4" as per your magento directory path and execute run.php file using browser.
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of adding `Api/GuestorderInterface.php` here?